# How do you get an object given a primary key name variable and a pk value?

Tags: python, django, django-models

If I have a variable for the name of the primary key how do I get an object given that variable and a primary key value?

For example

```
pk_name = 'username'
pk = 'bob'

class_name.objects.get(pk_name=pk)  # this obviously doesn't work because it looks for a field called pk_name
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [primary key shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut) to fetch an object by its primary key:

```
class_name.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

In general, if the field name is a variable, you can use a dictionary to provide the keyword arguments.

```
class_name.objects.get(**{field_name: 'field_value'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {"username":"bob"}
class_name.objects.get(**d)
```

maybe?